# Mysqli connection over ssl in php

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli

Made this code for testing:

```
include_once ('includes.inc.php');

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
    die("mysqli_init failed");
    exit;
}

$mysqli->ssl_set($mysqli, '/etc/mysql/ssl/server.key',
                          '/etc/mysql/ssl/server.crt',
                          '/etc/mysql/ssl/server.crt',
                           NULL,
                           NULL);

if (!$mysqli->real_connect(dbhost, dbusername, dbpassword, dbname, 3306, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL)){
   die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
} else {
   echo "Test connections";
}
```

In includes.inc.php i defined db info(name,user,pass...) and it works fine.
I wanted to make db class with this in __construct but it didnt work.

Before SSL i used this in my class:

```
    public function __construct(){
        /*
         * connect to database server and select the database
         */
        self::$mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost, dbusername, dbpassword, dbname);

        /*
         * check for errors
         */
        if (self::$mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

I need help with making __construct with ssl connection.
Tnx...

Comment: `but it didnt work` - please elaborate....

Comment: btw: you're using the server key in your client?